# Duda python - if

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo Python y estoy trabajando este código:

```
palabra = input('íngrese palabra: ').strip()
print(palabra)
letra = input('ingrese una letra:').strip()
if letra in palabra:
   print('bien')
```

La idea es que se ejecute el if cuando la letra ingresada esté en la palabra, todo va bien, pero cuando en la entrada de 'ingrese una letra' no ingreso nada y simplemente doy enter se ejecuta el if, porque pasa esto? ¿Y cuál sería la solución? Agradezco su atención.

Comment: Pasa por que las cadenas vacías `""` están en la palabra :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holiwis, el problema es que cuando están vacías, igualmente pregunta y es como "¿está Nada en Nada?" Cierto. Así que te tienes que preguntar si `letra` es algo y seleccionas la primera letra para que solo sea una letra (hay más formas de hacerlo, podrías hacer lo mismo con `palabra`) y preguntar si son distintos, pues Nada y Nada son iguales entonces Nada está en Nada.

```
palabra = input('Íngrese palabra: ').strip()
print(palabra)
letra = input('Íngrese una letra: ').strip()
if letra:
  letra = letra[0]
if letra in palabra and letra != palabra:
   print('bien')
```

No sé si me expliqué bien, cualquier duda comenta. Perdón, no lo hice bien, si el input en las dos variables es 'a' no imprime bien, ahora me lo pienso...

Edit:

```
palabra = input('Íngrese palabra: ').strip()
print(palabra)
letra = input('Íngrese una letra: ').strip()

if letra and letra[0] in palabra:
   print('bien')
```

Pruebas:

```
íngrese palabra: aaa
-> aaa
ingrese una letra: a
-> bien

íngrese palabra: 
->
ingrese una letra:

íngrese palabra: aaa
-> aaa
ingrese una letra: a
-> bien
```

Comment: Nop,   "¿está Nada en Nada?"  No es lo correcta en realidad lo que hace el `if` es verificar si "Nada" (cadena vacia) está en la palabra ingresada y siempre una cadena vacía está en otra cadena

Comment: Edítame la explicación si quieres

Answer (score 0):

Simple, le agregue una cosita a tu if, y listo no acepta cadena de solo enter

```py
palabra = input('íngrese palabra: ').strip()
print(palabra)
letra = input('ingrese una letra:').strip()
if letra in palabra and letra!='':
   print('bien')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: _¿Qué hace este código?_ Pulsa en [edit] y agrega más detalles. Lee [answer].